# How to code a MACD in an expert advisor that uses EMA instead of SMA for the signal line

Tags: mql4, mt4

```
#include <MovingAverages.mqh>

input int fast = 7;
input int slow = 26;
input int signallength =9;
input int closeoropen = 1; //close=0, open=1
input int movingavglength =114;
double ema, macd, signal;
double ind_buffer1[26], ind_buffer2[26];
bool sellsignaldone  = false;
bool buysignaldone = false;

void OnTick()
  { 
   ema = iMA(NULL,0,movingavglength,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);

//---- macd counted in the 1-st buffer
   for(int i=0; i<slow-1; i++)
      ind_buffer1[i]=iMA(NULL,0,fast,0,MODE_EMA,closeoropen,i)-iMA(NULL,0,slow,0,MODE_EMA,closeoropen,i);
//---- signal line counted in the 2-nd buffer
   for(int i=0; i<slow-1; i++)
      ind_buffer2[i]=iMAOnArray(ind_buffer1,0,signallength,0,MODE_EMA,i);

    macd = ind_buffer1[1];
    signal = ind_buffer2[1];
   
   if (macd > signal && macd<0 && Close[1]>ema && !buysignaldone && OrdersTotal()==0) {
      buysignaldone = true;
      OrderSend(NULL, OP_BUY,1/Ask, Ask, 3, Ask-(Ask*0.004), Ask+(Ask*0.008), "Buy Order",0,0,clrGreen);
      
   }
   if (macd < signal) {
      buysignaldone = false;
   }
   
   if (macd < signal && macd>0 && Close[1]<ema && !sellsignaldone && OrdersTotal()==0) {
      sellsignaldone = true;
      OrderSend(NULL, OP_SELL,1/Bid, Bid, 3, Bid+(Bid*0.004), Bid-(Bid*0.008), "Sell Order",0,0,clrRed);
   }
   
   if (macd > signal) {
      sellsignaldone = false;
   }
   
  }
```

You can't use `iMACD` for this. I'm not sure what I've done wrong but the signals are in the wrong place

[image]

Crossover is here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a much better result using `iOsMA`, but it's still not identical to the indicator.

```
#property strict

#include <MovingAverages.mqh>

input int fast = 7;
input int slow = 26;
input int signallength =9;
input int closeoropen = 1; //close=0, open=1
input int movingavglength =114;
double sma1, sma2, ema, macd, fastema, slowema, signal;
double ind_buffer1[26], ind_buffer2[26];
bool sellsignaldone  = false;
bool buysignaldone = false;

void OnTick()
  { 
    signal = iOsMA(NULL,0,fast,slow,signallength,closeoropen,1);
    fastema = iMA(NULL,0,fast,0,MODE_EMA,closeoropen,1);
    slowema = iMA(NULL,0,slow,0,MODE_EMA,closeoropen,1);
    macd = fastema-slowema;
    ema = iMA(NULL,0,movingavglength,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);

   if (signal>0 && macd<0 && Close[1]>ema && !buysignaldone && OrdersTotal()==0) {
      buysignaldone = true;
      OrderSend(NULL, OP_BUY,1/Ask, Ask, 3, Ask-(Ask*0.004), Ask+(Ask*0.008), "Buy Order",0,0,clrGreen);
      
   }
   if (macd < signal) {
      buysignaldone = false;
   }
   
   if (signal<0 && macd>0 && Close[1]<ema && !sellsignaldone && OrdersTotal()==0) {
      sellsignaldone = true;
      OrderSend(NULL, OP_SELL,1/Bid, Bid, 3, Bid+(Bid*0.004), Bid-(Bid*0.008), "Sell Order",0,0,clrRed);
   }
   
   if (macd > signal) {
      sellsignaldone = false;
   }
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the MACD indicator in the indicator folder, simply adding on the bottom the "ExponentialMAOnBuffer(...);" and "call" the second indicator in the expert using the iCustom function linked to the number of the index of the indicator. (es. for MACD (0,ExtMacdBuffer);(1,ExtSignalBuffer);)
the ea code now is more clear!